# Show Markers on Vector Images to build Custom Indoor Maps Android

Tags: android, maps, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-vectordrawable

I have a requirement to develop indoor maps UI on android. I have Svg/Vector images from the backend.
The map needs to be annotated with markers and labels based on coordinates on the Vector image received from different APIs at run time
The map should be zoomable and markers/labels need to adjust accordingly

[Sample Map with markers and labels on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk3io.jpg)

**Canvas Approach**
I have converted Vector to Bitmap. Have used Canvas to place markers on the bitmap. Since the vector image is huge, the bitmap conversion is impacting performance during placing markers. Also removing and adding new markers needs the canvas to be redrawn. It does not look like a good approach for my requirement.

**Layering approach**
The base map is shown first and corresponding markers and labels would be shown in another layer. The annotated layer and base map have to adjust themselves during interactions like zooming. I am trying to implement this, but could not decide where to start. Should I try using Surface View or Open GL?

Can anyone please guide me on how I can proceed with the layering approach? Any other better suggestions to display maps effectively would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I saw this message, I work at Point - https://www.point-maps.com/ and we have built a web-based solution to render indoor maps on all platforms. You can then manage all the styling and zooming levels for markers / POIs through our CMS. Our maps are built up in IMDF format.
If useful, let me know and we can see if we can help you.
Thanks